# Count number of pairs in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme

I have an assignment, where I need to count the number of pairs in the input.

This is what I have so far:

```
(define x 0)

(define number-of-pairs
  (lambda (v)
    (if (pair? v)
        (+ x 1)
        (+ x 0))))
```

And then I use it as follows:

```
(number-of-pairs (cons (cons 'a 'b) 'c))
```

Here it should produce 2, but it instead produces 1, as it only go through the function once.
If I try

```
(number-of-pairs 10)
```

it produces 0, as it should because there are no pairs.

Comment: This code does basically nothing but call `pair?` on the argument.

Comment: How can I make it into a loop for every pair there is?

Comment: I know what recursion is, but not sure how you would do it here?

Comment: Instead of adding just 1 to x, add 1 plus the number of pairs in the `tail`. No?

Comment: I made it work in some wierd way now :)

Comment: its customary to share with an edit, and if any of the three users who gave you answers were similar / helped guide you that you accept them as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to consider two cases:

1. What happens if the current element *is not* a pair?
2. What happens if the current element *is* a pair?

For the second case, we can add one to the total, because we know that the current element is a pair, and then we call the recursion on both parts of the pair - because we don't know if either one of them is in turn a pair.

Here's the general idea of what needs to be done, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (number-of-pairs v)
  (if (not (pair? v))
      <???>
      (+ <???>
         (number-of-pairs <???>)
         (number-of-pairs <???>))))
```

Use these examples for testing your procedure:

```
(number-of-pairs 10)
> 0

(number-of-pairs (cons (cons 'a 'b) 'c))
> 2

(number-of-pairs '(a b c))
> 3

(number-of-pairs (cons 'a (cons 'b (cons (cons 'c (cons (cons 'd '()) '())) '()))))
> 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the force, Luke!

Err. I mean use the design recipe.

See section 9.3 and 9.4 in How to Design Programs:

http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-13.html#node_sec_9.3

If you are unfamiliar with HtDP then the philosophy is to give you tools to systematically write program rather than just give examples.

Answer (score 0):

As it is written now, your code will only ever return a 1 or 0.  In order to make this procedure work as intended you will need to understand two important things about scheme:  how recursive calls work, and how assignment works.

Assignment:

I wrote a very in-depth breakdown of [assignment in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955074/scheme-assignment/10049112#10049112), but the short version in this case is that you are not changing the value of `x` when you call `(+ x 1)`.  If you want to actually change the value of a binding in scheme you have to use the `set!` procedure (but you really don't need to do that in this case).

Recursion:

Recall that recursion is when you call a procedure from within itself.  There are two necessary elements for a recursive solution:  a null value, and a reduction formula.

In the case of addition or subtraction your null value is 0, for multiplication it is 1, for `cons` it is the empty list `'()`.

The reduction formula is how you break down the problem into simpler pieces, or how you get the problem closer to being solved with each step.

Example:

```
(define count-elements
    (lambda (lst)
        (if (null? lst) 0 ; <-- I'm done? return the null value
            (+ 1 (count-elements (cdr lst)))))) ;<-- otherwise +1 and reduce the problem
```

Since this is homework, I won't explicitly solve this for you, but your answer should be in essentially the same form as count-elements, you'll just need another predicate to determine whether you actually need to add anything or not.